# What is meant by "tier price" in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, tierprice

Can anyone explain what is the tire price in magento and how it is being calculated ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tier price is where you can specify different costs for larger quantities.
You can set it up so that a quantity of 1 costs 10 euro, but a quantity of 2 will cost 9 euro per piece.

This should clear some things up: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-use-tier-pricing

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response. I referred the link as well as your answer. So the idea I grabbed from both is that for example if customer buys a particular product in large number of quantity he/she can get discount for that. When customer increase the quantity the discount will change according to the given configuration.

Comment: @Su123 Spot on mate! :)